# "There's no such thing as love; only proof of love"

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

Watching movies of Bernardo Bertolucci I noticed that he gave the same idea to several protagonists. And in pursuit to find the origin I found out that the phrase actually assigned to two french poets:

“There is no love; there are only proofs of love.”
― Pierre Reverdy ( http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/734580-there-is-no-love-there-are-only-proofs-of-love )

“There's no such thing as love; only proof of love.”
― Jean Cocteau ( http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/205793-there-s-no-such-thing-as-love-only-proof-of-love )

Curious about:

- how does the phrase sound in french?
- is there one author or...?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les deux auteurs, [Pierre Reverdy](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Reverdy) et [Jean Cocteau](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Cocteau), sont à l'origine de la même phrase, la voici en français :

> Il n'y a pas d'amour, il n'y a que des preuves d'amour.

The two persons, [Pierre Reverdy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Reverdy) and [Jean Cocteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Cocteau), are both author of the same phrase, here it is in French.

Comment: En fait, c'est Pierre Reverdy, pas du tout Jean Cocteau, qui l'a repris en disant "Comme disait Pierre Reverdy..." Cocteau, étant donné qu'il a repris la phrase, ne peut absolument pas en être l'auteur. La confusion vient du fait qu'il l'a complétée, mais bizarrement, on ne cite pas ce qu'il a dit, mais seulement la phrase qui n'est pas de lui!