# Expressing "There's no such thing as …" emphatically

Tags: traduction, expressions, emphase

All I've found are things such as ["(Sujet), ça n'existe pas"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/there-s-no-such-thing) or ["Il n'y a pas de..."](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12476/theres-no-such-thing-as-love-only-proof-of-love), but I find that too simple to convey the whole meaning of the English expression. As a non-native English speaker myself, I'm very much aware of the difficulties of translating this expression to other languages, but I want to make my French sentence somehow more emphatic than just a plain "n'existe pas". I believe "même" can be used as a sort of all-purpose word to emphasise what you're saying (I apologise beforehand if that's too simplistic), so I thought "(sujet) n'existe même pas" is a decent French rendering of the English expression, but [I haven't found this translation](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=no+such+thing+as), which made me wonder if this is actually an apt translation or if it doesn't really work here. Anyway, this is the sentence in context:

> Quand une femme se promène par les rues en portant un chapeau à fer avec des plumes, personne ne tourne sa tête parce qu'ils sont habitués à voir des gens habillés avec des vêtements très bizarres. En fait, **l’idée d’un vêtement bizarre n’existe même pas** dans l'esprit d'un londonien.

Does this sound okay, or should I just stick to "l’idée d’une vêtement bizarre, ça n’existe pas dans.."? Is the version with "même" more emphatic, or even natural sounding? Is there a better option?

Comment: I removed many comments please use the [chat] for discussion.

Comment: There is no such thing as *un chapeau à fer*, that might be *un chapeau en fer*.

Answer (score 9):

Your sentence is perfectly correct, but you could use the alternative:

> L'idée même d'un vêtement bizarre n'existe pas dans l'esprit londonien.

The difference is mostly stylistic, there is no real difference in meaning. It could be translated word-by-word to "the very idea of strange clothes doesn't exist in the londonian spirit."

Answer (score 5):

About *n'existe même pas*, the expression matches "there is no such thing" (more precisely "doesn't even exist"). I would have preferred this slightly modified sentence:

> L’idée qu'un vêtement puisse être bizarre n’existe même pas dans l'esprit d'un londonien.

or

> L’idée qu'un vêtement puisse être bizarre ne viendrait même pas à l'esprit d'un londonien.

Answer (score 5):

If the idea (and not just the thing behind the idea) that you’re referring to has been mentioned earlier, you could perhaps further emphasize the “no such idea” notion with "[**Une telle** idée (d’un vêtement bizarre) n'existe même pas](https://books.google.com/books?id=GWQ5AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA348&dq=%22une+telle+id%C3%A9e+n%27existe+pas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8-Ze14anMAhUGlh4KHe60Ap04ChDoAQgjMAE#v=onepage&q=%22une%20telle%20id%C3%A9e%20n%27existe%20pas%22&f=false)."

(example of usage from ‘Psychiatrische en Neurologische Bladen, Volume 5’ via ‘Google Books’)

To fit “[un tel/une telle](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/un%20tel)” (and the added emphasis it might provide) (link to 'Reverso') into your example less awkwardly than the above use of a parenthetical, perhaps you could say:

“ … des vêtements très bizarre.  Mais en fait qu’est-ce que c’est l’idée/notion d’un vêtement bizarre?  Pour plusieurs, une telle idée/notion n’existe même pas.”

Answer (score 4):

I think a direct translation of "There's no such thing" would be "*Il n'y a rien de tel*", and so you might say,

> En fait, il n'y a rien de tel dans l'esprit d'un londonien.

Or synonyms of *tel* include *pareil* and *semblable*.

Comment: No I don't think it's clear, actually the meaning of the quote in the OP wasn't clear to me. My answer is mostly meant as a suggested translation of what's in the title (only), not a rephrasing of what's quoted in the question.

Answer (score 2):

> En fait, l’idée d’un vêtement bizarre n’existe même pas dans l'esprit d'un londonien.

La tournure est correcte, compréhensible et ne choque pas, mais n'est pas complètement idiomatique. Il y a juste une faute d'orthographe : un **L**ondonien (les adjectifs de provenance géographique ne prennent pas de majuscule, mais les noms, si).

On peut déplacer l'adverbe *même*. C'est un peu plus idiomatique en langue soutenue, et ça renforce l'opposition entre l'idée de vêtement bizarre et l'esprit londonien en en donnant un aperçu dès le début de la phrase. Surtout, ça attire l'attention au bon endroit : l'objet principal de cette phrase, c'est l'idée de vêtement bizarre.

> En fait, l’idée même d’un vêtement bizarre n’existe pas dans l'esprit d'un londonien.

Je trouve le mot très générique *idée* un peu malheureux, même si on est plus dans le style que dans la langue. On peut le préciser en le qualifiant : c'est le fait qu'un vêtement peut être bizarre, pas le concept de vêtement qui est en cause.

> En fait, **l’idée même qu'un vêtement puisse être bizarre n’existe pas dans l'esprit d'un londonien**.

Une autre amélioration est de remplacer *idée* par le mot *concept* qui est plus précis. De plus, c'est un des rares cas en français où on peut omettre l'article, et c'est plus idiomatique.

> En fait, le concept même de vêtement bizarre n’existe pas dans l'esprit d'un Londonien.

On peut aussi réordonner la phrase. Une tournure plus simple pour dire que quelqu'un conçoit quelque chose est « avoir le concept de … », surtout utilisé sous forme négative.

> En fait, **les Londoniens n'ont même pas le concept de vêtement bizarre**.

On peut aussi dépersonnaliser un peu.

> En fait, l'esprit londonien n'admet même pas le concept de vêtement bizarre.

(J'ai mis en gras les deux tournures que je préfère.)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I have a question, though. Jlliagre proposed *L’idée qu'un vêtement **puisse** être bizarre n’existe même pas...*, while you propose *l’idée même qu'un vêtement **peut** être bizarre n’existe pas...*. Is there any difference between the indicative and the subjunctive form? Are both correct?

Comment: @Yay With both sentence constructions, both the subjunctive (*puisse*) and the indicative (*peut*) can be used. On reflection, here, I think the subjunctive is more neutral, and more appropriate. The indicative implies that the speaker considers that clothes can be strange, and thus that Londoners are blind to an existing concept. In informal speech, the indicative wouldn't have this implication, it would just be a substitution for the subjunctive, but this sentence isn't informal enough for that.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is to use the negation `point`. It basically means `not at all`. It's hard to find support for this claim on [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/point), but I have seen this form of empahsis used often, at least in a literary context.

> L’idée d’un vêtement bizarre n’existe *point*

Comment: This is correct but the negation point is quite dated now and we tend not to use it anymore. It is a sophisticated word mostly use in literary context.

Comment: Thanks @0x1gene! I assumed as much but it is nice to get confirmation. If it were still common I feel it would be a good fit.

Answer (score -2):

I would say something like:

> Il n'existe pas quelque chose de bizarre comme ...

I have never heard about the "l’idée d’un vêtement bizarre n’existe même pas", but it is easy to understand the meaning for French speakers.

Comment: I noticed that "de bizarre" was wrong thanks to you and made an edit. However, I made a search and couldn't find exister in the verbe d'etat list. https://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081115115123AAUS9rD @AnneAunyme

Comment: You are right, it is not a "verbe d'état", I wrote my comment too quickly. What I wanted to say is that *exister* is not transitive. In English you don't "exist something", but "something exists", that is the same in French.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Well, I don't think so. In this case "il" doesn't really exist, we just turned the phrase and had to put "il" in it. Examples: "Il existe 3raçes de chien..." and "3raçes de chien existe...", the first one sounds much better and is what I normally use.

Comment: I can't find anything to back up my point, but neither can't I find anything to back up yours, so I am just gonna open a new question about that.

Comment: I am going to add the link of your question: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18868/transitivit%c3%a9-du-verbe-exister